# Akka, Generic ActorRef?

Tags: scala, generics, akka, actor

I'm rather new to Scala so this may be a trivial question. I'm trying to put together a simple project in Akka and I'm not sure how to handle a situation where I need to store a reference to an actor of a constrained type. 
Let's assume I have an actor trait

```
trait MyActorTrait extends Actor
```

Then somewhere else I would like to define another trait with a member

```
def reference: ActorRef[MyActorTrait]
```

That obviously doesn't work since ActorRef doesn't care about the target actor's type (or does it?). Is there any way to constrain the `reference` to only accept references to actors that extend `MyActorTrait`?

Answer (score 2):

By design, there is no way you can access the underlying `Actor` through `ActorRef` (or, pretty much, any other way). So, constraining the type like you describe is pointless, there would be absolutely no difference in what you can do with `ActorRef[Foo]` vs. `ActorRef[Bar]`.

Not saying, this is a good thing (few things in Akka can be characterized that way IMO), but that's just the way it is.

Comment: In such case if I want to apply some compile time constrains I should i.e.  create a transport object which can only be created at the point where the type of an actor can be determined, i.e. with some sort of creation function returning an Either or Option, or even from within the actor itself - would this make sense?

Comment: I don't know what you are saying. Not sure what is "transport object", but if it can only be created where the type of the actor can be determined, it sounds like it should be created _inside_ the actor itself, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to reference an actor in another actor is not right. Actors form a hierarchy. So it gives you a path to refer an actor. There are mainly three ways you could reference another actor using

- Absolute Paths

```
 context.actorSelection("/user/serviceA")
```

- Relative Paths

```
context.actorSelection("../brother") ! msg
```

- Querying the Logical Actor Hierarchy

```
context.actorSelection("../*") ! msg
```

You may have a look at the doc - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I believe I've found a way. 
First I create a trait which will preserve the actor type

```
trait TypedActorRef[T <: Actor] {
  def reference: ActorRef
  type t = T
}
```

Then implement a generic apply which instantiates a private case class extending the trait

```
object TypedActorRef {
  private case class Ref[T <: Actor] (reference: ActorRef) extends TypedActorRef[T]
  def apply[T <: Actor](actor: T) = {
    Ref[T](actor.self)
  }
}
```

With that I can keep a reference which is restricted an actor of the type I want.

```
trait OtherActor extends Actor

trait MyActor extends Actor
{
  def otherActorsReference: TypedActorRef[OtherActor]
}
```

This seems OK to me, at least this seems not to upset the compiler, but I'm not sure if this solution prevents from creating other extensions of the TypedActorRef which may not respect the same constraints.

Comment: That won't work. You can't instantiate `Actor` outside of the context of `ActorRef`. 
But if don't mind a typed _wrapper_ to `ActorRef` rather than `ActorRef` _itself_, 
you can have that with something like `def apply[T <: WorkflowActor](factory: => T) = Ref[T](context.actorOf(Props(factory)))`

Comment: @Dima what is in the ```context``` in your example?

Comment: Just try doing `new WorkflowActor()`. You'll see what I mean

Comment: @Dima, are you able to provide a minimal example how your solution should be used. As mentioned I'm new to Scala... :)

Comment: The example is in my comment above. Is anything unclear?

Comment: Atually it is.. What I understand from your snippet is that you create such typed reference at the moment of an actor creation, is that correct? However I do not undertand where exactly the snippet should be used: in the companion of TypedActorRef? Some sort of base class of an Actor, a mixin trait? I'm aware that from an experienced Scala developer's point of view your snippet may be obvious but if I was one of them I wouldn't ask such question ;)

Comment: It's what your `apply` method should look like ... But you'll also need to pass the `context` in actually. Forgot about that